# Hide the contents filled by each anonymous user on Excel Online

Tags: excel-online

In order to fill a spreadsheet, I need ask to 50 people to fill it using Excel Online.

Each person must fill a column in the spreadsheet. After that, when he quits the document, is there any possibility to hide what he filled to any other user (except me)?

I would also accept a Google Spreadsheets answer if this turns out to be impossible in Excel Online.

Comment: I have narrowed this down a bit so that it is not "Too Broad".

Answer (score 2):

You should [create an Excel survey](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Surveys-in-Excel-hosted-online-5FAFD054-19F8-474C-97EC-B606FCDA0FF9) so that nobody knows who else is filling out the form and they can't edit anyone else's responses.

1. Go to [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/)
2. Select **New > Excel survey**
   [image: select from the menu]
3. You will then go through a wizard asking you to create questions.
   If you want to make people answer all of them then mark each question as **Required**.
   [image: make them all required to make them all required]
4. Add as many questions necessary
5. Click **Share survey**
6. Copy the survey link that is generated
7. Share the link to how every many people you want to answer the questions
   [image: go answer it if you wish]

They will not need an account and can answer the questions anonymously.

But they are able to answer the survey again by reloading the page, so you may end up with people filling out the form more than once.

The spreadsheet will appear with the rest of those under your account.

If you ever want to edit the questions you can by:

> Insert > Survey > Edit Survey

Comment: I already know this feature of Excel Online but it is not possible to use the content of some cells for creating questions and choices of answers. In my case I have 50 rows in my spreadsheet and I want to ask use to choose 10 of it and make a sorted choice (by puting numbers in the column).

Comment: That is something you should have mentioned in the question originally because the way you have it when first posted you don't mention if you have tried the survey option or how it doesn't fit. It may be better to ask a new question based on using surveys to create future answers based on how the user answered one before